# How to use the locally installed version of Syncfusion.Angular in Angular projects?

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I have installed **Syncfusion.Angular** in my system:

[Syncfusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZrJE.png)

I can run the control panel and see all the resources and documentation. But, I don't know how to use it in my project. The official documentation does not explain the offline usage of **Syncfusion.Angular** (locally installed). How can I use locally installed controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncfusion components are also available in the npm registry you can install the components as an npm package and you can use them in your project. Please refer to the below documentation on how to utilize the Syncfusion angular components as npm packages. Also, the packages in the npm will be the same as in the installer.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/getting-started/angular-cli/